# In python, how to integrate function with different range?

Tags: python

I need to calculate the integral of the `G(prec)` function, and the range of the integral would be the line-by-line values. It is giving the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool (), a.item (), a.any () or a.all ().**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math 
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import sympy as sp
import quadpy


data=pd.read_csv('alto_paraguai_mensal_vf.csv')

prec=data['PRCP']

A=np.log(np.mean(prec))-(1/len(prec))*np.sum(np.log(prec))


a=(1/4*A)*(1+np.sqrt(1+(4*A/3)))
b = np.mean(prec)/a

def f(x):
    return x**(a-1)*np.exp(-x)
i=quad(f,0,np.inf) #intervalo

def g(prec):
    return (1/((b**a)*i))*(prec**(a-1))*np.exp(-prec/b)

p=(1/((b**a)*i))
def G(prec): 
    return p*prec**(a-1)*np.exp(-prec/b)
s=quad(G,0,prec)
```

Comment: Which line did you get that error?

Comment: s=quad(G,0,prec). I need that the range 0 to prec, in each line one value.

Comment: review this please https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4grhQ5Y_MWo

Comment: I saw this video, but it don't show how to calculate integration with range diference.

Comment: I need to calculate the range 0 tô X. X ia value each line of the table